# play a role as vs play a role of

Tags: prepositions

I would like to describe someone's role in the company.
My editor and I disagree on the use of "as" vs "of" in the sentence

> X also plays a role ***as*** (job-function)

vs

> X also plays a role ***of*** (job-function).

My opinion is that "plays a role as" indicates a greater impact on the role and the company, whereas "plays a role of" is more "does the job".

My old dictionary of English language haven't helped and a google search says the "of"-use is the most common, but is also mostly used differently than what I propose.

Thoughts?

Comment: As you probably know, the original meaning of _role_ is a part in a play, so it does mean _does the job of_. I don't think the distinction that you imagine exists.

Comment: It is very likely that when used alone, _as_ can be thought of as a semantic (not grammatical) version of _is_ -- it links and identifies things.

Comment: Your asking users to choose between two wrong answers if some "job-function" is to be the object of the preposition because a "role" would indicate a *job title* (e.g., bookkeeper), not "job-function" (e.g., bookkeeping).

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Thanks- Sorry, I am actually using the jobtitle, not the job-function. I did not realise the distinction between function and title.

Comment: I suggest that would be either "plays a role as…" or 
"plays the role of…" and that's based on listening, not research.

Comment: [...] has the role of x

Answer (score 0):

Well, ***as*** already means ***in the role of***, so it is somewhat redundant to say *play a role as*:

> As + noun means ‘in the role of' ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-or-like))

> in the capacity, character, condition, or role of
> works ***as*** *an editor* ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as))

Your probably want to stress that this person's contribution in the company, and this would be the meaning of ***to play a part/role in something***:

> to be involved in something, especially in a way that is important
>
> - She ***played a key role*** in campaigning for equal opportunities in the workplace. ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/play-a-part-role-in-something))

So if you really want to keep your ***as*** instead of ***of***, your sentence will read much better if you add an adjective modifying *role*:

> X also plays a(n) *important/significant/key* role ***as*** (job-function)